# Migration from MySQL to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, database-migration

Right now I have three tables A, B and C in mysql database:

```
Table A   Table B   Table C 
id         id        id       
           FK_A                  
           FK_C
```

I should write a service which returns results from table A giving to it ids from table C:

```
request:{
ids_from_tableC: []
}
response:{
ids_from_tableA:[]
}
```

So I have some questions:

1. When I do migration, should I migrate joined query for one indice or two different queries for two indices?
2. If two indices, can I join indices and get desirable result?

It would be cool, if you could help me :)

I attempted to write joined query, but there are only one data (1 row), but in MySQL there are more than 10k.

Comment: I would definitely go with a JOIN query that denormalizes your tables into full-fledge documents as this is usually the best practice with ES in those cases. Can you show what you tried so far?

Comment: @Val Thank you!

I've written joins and group concat to denormalize tables. Now my ES looks like this:

`"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "books",
        "_id" : "5838",
        "_source" : {
          "foreign_ids" : "1,2,3",
          "id" : 5838
        }
      },`

Can I write query to filter by foreign_ids, for example:

`request:[1,2,3]
response:[5838]

request:[1,2]
response:[5838]

request:[1,4]
response:[]`

Because, book with id 5838 doesn't contain foreign_id 4.

Should I convert my string "1,2,3" to array [1,2,3]? If yes, how?

Comment: Can you update your question? it will be more legible than in comments

Comment: Your answer was helping me, thanks!